# How to show that $E[E[X\mid Y]\mid Y] = E[X\mid Y]$

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation, estimation

I'm reading a little proof about how the estimation error (based on the conditional expectation estimator, $E[X\mid Y]$) has zero expectation, and at one point the author used the equality that the conditional expectation of the estimator on $Y$ == the estimator itself, i.e. $E[E[X\mid Y]|Y] = E[X\mid Y]$. Can somebody show me how that's derived?

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the law of iterated expectation...

See textbook screenshot:

[image: E[E[X|Y]|Y] = E[X|Y]]

Comment: Depends on how general your definition of the condition expectation is. What's your definition of $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$?

Comment: I'd like to see how the textbook defines (or treats) $E[E[X|Y]|Z]$ if $Y$ and $Z$ are different.

Comment: @BarryCipra Why? (Sorry but I cannot see what you have in mind here. The paragraph in the question is most probably not the definition of conditional expectation given in the book but a simple property.)

Comment: @Did, I do not know what the conventions are for using conditional expectation notation.  Naively, it seems to me that $E[E[X|Y]|Z]$ should always equal $E[X|Y]$.  So to the extent that the OP is asking how the notation gives a particular result, I'm basically asking what does the notation mean?

Comment: @BarryCipra It is untrue that $E(E(X\mid Y)\mid Z)=E(X\mid Y)$ in general, actually the identity holds if and only if $E(X\mid Y)$ is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable, which in turn could be guaranteed if $\sigma(Y)\subseteq\sigma(Z)$, that is, if $Y$ is some function of $Z$, but not otherwise. The notation $E(E(X\mid Y)\mid Z)$ refers to $E(T\mid Z)$, where $T$ denotes the random variable $T=E(X\mid Y)$.

Comment: @Did, as I said, it's a naive understanding.  Your reply is a wonderfully cogent explanation.   I'm happy to delete all this if you think it's all clutter.

Comment: @BarryCipra I did not say that. If you reread my comments, you will see that first, I was puzzled by your question, then I asked for explanations to see if I had missed something, and finally I tried to explain the relevant mathematical stuff.

Comment: @Did, and I didn't say you said it!  All I meant was, **if** you think no one else will benefit from reading our back and forth, then I'm happy to remove my half of it.  In particular, my initial comment is really just a tortuous form of fgp's, so I'm at a loss now to justify having posted it.

Comment: @BarryCipra My final take on this affair is: No big deal.

Comment: please keep the comments as I find them helpful...also for those interested in more context, my screenshot is from page 225, Introduction to Probability, 2ed by Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional expectation is a function of the conditioning variable: $E(X\mid Y)=g(Y)$

Further, for any function of a random variable, $E(h(Y)\mid Y)=h(Y)$. This might be more obvious to you if we regard the conditioning as a fixed value:  $E(h(Y)\mid Y=y)=h(y)$

Comment: thanks! this is probably silly but I just want to make sure: so the expectation of a random variable given itself is just the same random variable, i.e. $$E[X|X]=X$$ right? (same goes for the function of a random variable)

Comment: This is correct.